# Prevent users from opening multiple windows to the same web app

Tags: java, struts

Let me know if it's possible to prevent users from opening the same java web in multiple IE window. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reliable way to prevent an individual from opening the very same webpage in multiple browser windows/tabs or even different browsers/machines/phones.

You need to solve the problem for which you think that this is the solution differently. For example, just don't store request scoped data in the session scope.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to prevent multiple requests from the same client, you can look into your http server configuration. there should be some settings to allow you to limit the number of concurrent connections for an ip and timeout settings. this feature is typically used to ensure quality of service and protect from DoS attacks.

(this feature is not available on all http servers and the configuration is vendor dependent so you have to consult your http server documentation.)